# Не обновляется таблица при использовании двоеточия в значении параметра C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользователь иногда может вводить значения с двоеточием в столбец "NZU", но mysql ругается на такой синтаксис, выдавая ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':2' at line 1

Данные обновляются так:

```
string id = dgvZU.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                string query = "UPDATE zu SET NZU=@n, AdressZU=@a, PloshadZU=@p WHERE NZU = " + id;

                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = Connect.con;
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", nZU.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", addressZU.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", ploshadZU.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно изменены!");

                cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Я так понимаю, проблема существует из-за того, что nzu является первичным ключом. Но препод хочет именно такой вариант, чтобы туда можно было ввести значение с двоеточием. Собственно, как обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: Проблема возникает только тогда, когда пытаетесь вставить значение с двоеточием?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да

Comment: Непонятно, почему вы 3 параметра передаёте как полагается, а четвертый просто склеиваете с запросом в строку?

Comment: Ну и как бы, если вы строковый параметр используете, его наверно надо в кавычки взять. Хотя лучший способ - передать его как параметр.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, сам не понимаю, почему я так невнимательно написал)